# Is there a way to adjust a UIModalTransitionStyle speed/duration?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uimodaltransitionstyle

I want to use `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`, but just have it happen a bit quicker.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this class method instead:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.view
                  toView:newView.view
                duration:0.1f
                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
              completion:nil];
```

Ps:the options is: **UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft**
not **UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft**